# What is the major authority (ies) for big C++ projects?

Tags: c++, projects

For many years, I have been re-reading John Lakos's classic [Large-Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620). Not only it was the first guidebook of this kind, but it also  revolutionized  how to develop a project  in C++, in an efficient fashion to this day!

Do you feel his ideas are outdated now? Some C++ techniques  in the book are in fact  old (don't forget that book has been written  before the latest standard was published) .

What's a good authority to  guide building  of a big system in C++ nowadays.

Don't get me wrong, I am not giving up Lakos at all. It will always be referenced for me, and occupy a prime location on the bookshelf.

Thanks

Comment: I personally have never rated that book. But unfortunately, I don't know a better one.

Comment: Unfortunately, TTBOMK, there is no newer book covering this subject. `:(`

Comment: If that newer book existed, what should be in it that isn't in Lakos' book?

Comment: Lakes's book predominately  relies on the 20th century assumptions about technology and software methodologies. The new Book should rely on 21st century paradigms. Though a lot of fundamental principles remained largely unchanged.

Comment: It was a decent book at the time, however it hardly "revolutionised" c++ systems development...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, his next book, [Scalable C++: Component-Based Development, is anticipated in 2006.](http://www.devconnections.com/shows/CPPFall2005/default.asp?c=2&s=67&i=1655)

I don't think it has ever came to fruition... one day it may!

Also, Agile Principles and patterns are widespread and effective software developing paradigm. I am shifting my gears in that directions.

Check out this book: [Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135974445)

Answer (score 4):

The book's scope is narrow:

1. Move implementation details out of the header and into the CPP file
2. Avoid cyclic dependencies.

Although it goes into a lot of detail on these topics, the topics themselves are very narrow.

A lot, and IMO most, of the challenge of a "big C++ project" is elsewhere ...

- Version control for big teams / many branches
- Scheduling
- Integration testing
- Defining requirements
- Reliability
- Maintenance

... but these topics aren't C++-specific.

Comment: +1 And I would add "how to do modular decomposition using LIBRARIES", something most developers are woefully ignorant of.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the following guys are regarded as leading authorities on C++:

1. [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/)
2. [Scott Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/)
3. [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/)
4. [Andrei Alexandrescu](http://erdani.org/index2.html)

The books/articles by all of them teach the best C++ practices.

Comment: None of these have written books addressing the question.

Comment: I am talking about designing a BIG system... not language issues. I also follow these guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Last I heard from someone (I am 2nd connected to Lakos, if that matters) he was still working on his latest book in 2008.